# Auto-sizing images in a HTML CSS block as browser window resizes

Tags: html, css, image, scale

I'm after some help please.
I'm trying to allow a block of 3 images to scale / resize as the browser window is re-sized, whist staying aligned.

I created a JSFiddle to show the initial layout of how images will be placed here: http://jsfiddle.net/headshot_harry/3eEDH/2/

The code I have which contains the images is here:

```
<div style="width: 100%; margin: 0 auto -80px auto;">
    <div style="display: inline-block; border: 1px solid black; padding: 3px; text-align: center;">
        <div style="display: inline-block; margin: 0 4px 0 0; padding: 0; background-color: White; border: 1px solid black;
            width: 51%; vertical-align: top;">
            <img src="http://www.zen87038.zen.co.uk/image/glove/gs_golf_glove2.png" style="width: 100%;" />
        </div><div style="display: inline-block; margin: 0; margin: 0; width: 26%;">
            <div style="border: 1px solid black; margin-bottom: 3px;">
                <img src="http://www.zen87038.zen.co.uk/image/glove/gs_golf_glove4.png" style="width: 100%; background-color: White; margin-bottom: 4px;" />
            </div>
            <div style="border: 1px solid black;">
                <img src="http://www.zen87038.zen.co.uk/image/glove/gs_golf_glove4.png" style="width: 100%; background-color: White;" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically, it scales reasonably well, but I can't figure out how to get it to stay aligned. I think I've got way ahead of myself and got totally mixed up on the percentages.

As the JSFiddle above shows, I need to have one image on the left hand side of the block and 2 images sitting on top of each other occupying the right hand side of the block ideally with a small 3/4/5 pixel (whatever works) gap in-between images. Then when the browser is shrunk or enlarged I'd like the images to also shrink or enlarge.

Would anyone be able to help me with this please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to make sure your site is responsive. In order to make the changes to the img as the site re-sizes. You will need to make your img size into percents.  Check out the example. http://designsbycamaron.net/equal-image-heightswidth/
Here is a direct link to my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/KuEk3/4/light/).

```
img {
   width: 80%;
   height: auto;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to set your elements' width to a relative value (percent for example), like this:

```
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 50%; background-color: blue; height: 200px;
            vertical-align: top;">test left</div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 40%; ">
        <div style="background-color: red; height: 99px; margin-bottom: 2px;">test right top</div>
        <div style="background-color: red; height: 99px;">test right bottom</div>
    </div>
```

This way you can always resize and the element will resize to that percentage of the parent-element (sometimes you will need to set the position of the parent to relative though).

I updated your Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3eEDH/1/

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help - I must apologise, I uploaded the wrong Fiddle. New one is here: http://jsfiddle.net/headshot_harry/3eEDH/2/  (updated original question as well)